# Как читать log-файл в режиме реального времени через FTP?

Tags: java

Интересует реализация чтения log-файла бесперебойно (может и с небольшими лагами) через FTP. В интеренете я вижу примеры реализации через локальный компьютер, но меня интересует через FTP.

Comment: Протокол FTP не поддерживает функций, способных обеспечить такой доступ к файлу.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, а если не через ftp? Я лично юзал только такое: подключение через `ssh` и далее `tail -f file`. Жить можно, но может есть что-то удобнее?

Comment: В ftp вроде есть возможность указать с какого места начать загрузку файла?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev протокол может и не поддерживает, но можно написать свой сервер, который: 1. не поддерживает команду вывода размера файла 2. при старте чтения будет отдавать файл только с конца, и никогда не остановится. Обычный клиент который поддерживает прием файла в виде потока может построчно считывать данные. Только вот непонятно зачем здесь использовать ftp.